# Why isn't the LinkedList going through all the entities?

Tags: java, collision

I am trying to develop collision detection. For some reason, the collision is working for the last entity in the LinkedList. I have tried my best to debug it using the console to see where it's stopping, but I had no luck. All the other entities are not working, only the last one is. Here is the code :

```
public class Player implements Entity {

Image player;

public float x = 100f;
public float y = 100f;

boolean canGoLeft = true;
boolean canGoRight = true;
boolean canGoUp = true;
boolean canGoDown = true;

public float speed = 0.15f;

public Rectangle leftRect;
public Rectangle rightRect;
public Rectangle topRect;
public Rectangle bottomRect;

int i = 0;

Entities entities = new Entities();

public Player() {

}

public void update(GameContainer game, int delta) {

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        if(canGoRight) {
            x += speed * delta; 
        }
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        if(canGoLeft) {
            x -= speed * delta;
        }
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
        if(canGoUp) {
            y -= speed * delta; 
        }
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        if(canGoDown) {
            y += speed * delta;
        }
    }

    for(Entity entity : Game.entities.entities) {
        checkCollisions(entity);
    }

}

public void render(GameContainer game, Graphics g) {

    leftRect = new Rectangle(x, y + 5, 2, 80);
    rightRect = new Rectangle(x + 45, y + 5, 2, 80);
    topRect = new Rectangle(x + 6, y, 36, 2);
    bottomRect = new Rectangle(x + 6, y + 90, 36, 2);

    //rect = new Rectangle(200, 100, 60, 88);

    try {
        player = new Image("res/Player.png");
        player.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    player.draw(x, y, 60, 88);

    //g.draw(leftRect);
    //g.draw(rightRect);
    //g.draw(topRect);
    //g.draw(bottomRect);

}

public void checkCollisions(Entity entity) {

    // Collision Detection

    canGoLeft = !leftRect.intersects(entity.getRect());
    canGoRight = !rightRect.intersects(entity.getRect());
    canGoDown = !bottomRect.intersects(entity.getRect());
    canGoUp = !topRect.intersects(entity.getRect());

}

public Rectangle getRect() {
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** iterating through your entire list, but checkCollisions overwrites the value of canGoLeft, canGoRright, etc. every time it is called.

You should do something like

```
canGoLeft = canGoLeft && !leftRect.intersects(entity.getRect());
```

Comment: This does not work. When I collide, it stops me, but it does not stop stopping me from going that way. Why?

Comment: Can you give an example, I'm confused.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to explain. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Assuming you've implemented the change that JVMATL suggests (which I agree with, BTW), it sounds as though what you're saying is, for turn N, you try to go left, and canGoLeft at some point tells you "I can't go left anymore". And then you go right once or twice, and then try to go left again, but because canGoLeft never got reset, you can't ever go left anymore.  Sorry if that sounds confusing, but I see a couple problems: 1) you need to reset the variables if you move a different direction, and 2) you probably should check whether you can move in a direction before you update x or y.

Comment: @shoover is right. I believe you need to reset canGoDown/up/ etc. back to true before entering the checkCollision for() loop.

Comment: My other point was that you probably should check whether you can move in a direction *before* you move in that direction, rather than after you have moved in that direction. Your code is modifying x or y before checking whether that modification is "legal".